# Access Local Storage variable in all the web sites viewed on a browser

Tags: javascript, local-storage, internet-explorer-11

I have two of my websites built with asp .net .In one web site I am creating a local Storage variable called count.In my another application i cannot access this local local storage variable.Two web sites are HtML 5 based.

Is there any way of accessing the local storage variable in another site also.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: local storage can't be shared

Answer (score 6):

LocalStorage is like cookies: you can't access one other website's variables. It's designed to avoid malicious websites to access other website's personal data.

Answer (score 2):

Basically,localstorage is an advanced version of cookies that we initially used(with enhanced storage capacity).The values can be stored in key value pairs and accessed along the course of the same application.In your case,it is not possible to use localstorage as it is crossapplication.